# What technology would you suggest to manage hundreds of millions of strings

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds

I am looking at a project that involves managing hundreds of millions of strings (varchar(100)) and some related data (a few ints, some floats, etc.).  The project owner has mandated that this be performed in the Amazon cloud.

These strings will be updated continuously (about 1% per day) via batch jobs.  There will be several key reports that will run daily against this data.

As a SQL Server DBA my first instinct is to put it into an EC2 instance running SQL Server, however I would like to be able to present other option (RDS, MySQL, non-RDBMS, etc.)

Any suggestions?  What has worked for you in the past?

Comment: A gazebo? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biggest_ball_of_twine  :)

Comment: You would need to provide more information on the access patterns, how data is stored/retrieved (i.e. key-value, data trees, etc.), and the throughput requirement to get a better idea of what may be most appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Amazon Cloud you have the following options:

- [DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) - KeyValue NoSQL highly scalable Database. You can store almost infinite number of keys with it. The two use cases for it are to do key lookup, and key+range scan. To have a more complex query against it for reports it not recommended.
- [Redshift](http://aws.amazon.com/redshift/) - Data warehouse in huge scale that is working against standard SQL clients (PostgreSQL drivers). It is also can support almost unlimited number of rows in a columnar structure. You can run all your favorite reports on top of it.
- [CloudSearch](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/) - Very scalable search indexer with the ability to use the attributes for creation of facets (how many items in each range). Depends on your data structure and query types, it might be useful.
- [RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) - Relational Database Service, which support MySQL, Oracle and MS-SQL engines. This is similar to running these databases on standard EC2 instances, but with some DBA tasks (Backup, Restore, Scaling...) done easier.
- EC2 - put your favorite NoSQL (MongoDB, Redis, Couchbase...) or RDBMS (PostgreSQL, MySQL...) on any instance types, including the beefy machines with tons of memory and disks.

Comment: Thanks Guy.  Since I posted the question, I have continued my research.  We will be using a blend of EC2, DynamoDB and CloudSearch.

Answer (score 1):

This probably would come down to what you want to do with it. RDS is nothing more than managed SQL Server, Oracle or Mysql. There are some limitations as to what features are supported however.

You might get some benefit out of the NoSQL systems, not so much as a master storage location, but somewhere you can store prepared reporting data.

You may find use for EMR to manipulate data for use in reporting.